# Are questions on reading of old handwritings on topic?

Tags: discussion

There is an inconsistent voting on questions regarding deciphering of old handwritings:

- [Read old handwritten Text](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4716/read-old-handwritten-text)
- [Erkennung einer alten Handschrift](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4656/erkennung-einer-alten-handschrift)
- [How can I find out what is written on an image of the Spiezer chronicle?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8494/please-translate-this-text-for-me-and-tell-me-if-its-an-old-photo-or-new)

This makes me believe that we should discuss whether such questions are welcome here or not.

Comment: Sadly the answers and comments on your question seem to be long in coming.  Feeling like the unintended ghost light some clarification/consens on this context seems desirable to me.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Die Frage geistert nun schon seit vielen Jahren herum. Immer wieder werden Posts geschlossen, die um Entzifferung von Handschriften bitten (aber auch nicht konsequent). Das Fazit der Meta-Diskussion, sichtbar an den Votes, ist m.E., dass requests dieser Art legitim sind. Ich teile diese Ansicht, aber es scheint, dass die Minderheitenmeinung sich in der Praxis durch close votes durchsetzt. Ich wünsche mir, dass die Moderatoren eine Empfehlung über die Behandlung solcher Posts aussprechen. Rein statistisch scheint es nicht übermäßig viele Fragen dieser Art zu geben.

Comment: Man kann das natürlich als service requests sehen, für die in diesem Forum kein Platz ist, aber ich behaupte, dass das für viele Fragen mit anderen tags genauso ist.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Why handwritings?

We may want to accept reading/decoding requests for old handwritings for the following reasons:

- Handwritings are an integral part of the history of the German language.
- Old handwritings are never trivial. They are a challenge even for natives so the "finer point" is always given.
- We do have a base of users who can do this and who are also willing to do so.
- There is no other place where people could go to. This gives us a chance to stand out from other language sites.
- For some of us it may also be an interesting puzzle to solve where we all can learn a lot on the German language, culture, or European history.
- A community driven decoding of old handwritings may lead to amazingly good results.
- We want to be open to many different approaches to understand the German language. This  should not be restricted to learners help, grammar issues, spelling, or  word-usage requests. Questions on reading, and understanding of handwritten documents will widen the spectrum of topics here.

#### Prerequisites

We still may not want to see all those possible questions flood our site. We should expect some prerequisites before we can accept them:

- The question must give the context from were the original was taken.
- There should be at least some general, historical, or scientific interest in such a  question.
- We may not want to see crumbly notes from the attic or shopping lists from a supermarket someone found and is just curious about.
- The more a question appears to be helpful for, or interesting to future visitors the more likely it will stay.
- Whenever we are faced with contemporary handwritings we will have to take extra care that they are of general interest.

Answer (score 2):

There surely is no doubt that old (and new) handwritings are an important part of our history and our language. 
The question is: Who can benefit from a standard question on Stackexchange and in which ways?

1. The person asking the question can get quick and good help.
2. The members of this board can step up to the challenge and discover new aspects of the german language.
3. Other users who are having the same problem can find the answer by searching the web.

Now, for old handwritings, the first two points definitely fit. The benefit for other users may be very limited, as the subject is very specific, but in my opininon, this does not mean that we should ignore such questions.

I think that such deciphering requests are great opportunities for us to grow further and have some fun along the way, but we should only accept documents that have some sort of historical or cultural relevance like the three examples you mentioned. And of course, we should do more than just decipher it without further comments and references. But honestly, when have we ever not done that?

After the problem was solved, we should also consider to edit the original question and add tags like "Deciphering of an old handwriting by Martin Luther" so that search engines can find the post - given the slight chance that another person someday might be looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I have to apologize for my doubt of being "On Topic" of [Please translate this text for me and tell me if it's an old photo or new](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8494/please-translate-this-text-for-me-and-tell-me-if-its-an-old-photo-or-new).
I'm spending most time on Stack  Overflow and questions just asking for a solution, showing no research effort are off topic there. 
I related this question wrongly with questions just dumping a text here with the demand to translate it . I actually did not vote to close and only expressed my doubts, which reading the help section of this site seem to be unfounded.

Comment: Now, what is your personal view: Do you like the idea of having "please deciper this old handwriting" questions here? What would you think of what requirements they should meet to be interesting?

Comment: As a puzzle I'd find them interesting. Maybe I'd expect some more background research and a clear (maybe historical) demarcation to avoid that for example someone  asks to translate a scanned shopping chit or list of homework questions.

Comment: +1. I was about to post this same answer when I read your post. It would have been encouraging for others if asker would have said which part(s) he already had deciphered.

Answer (score -3):

### Wieso sind die Pro-Argumente zu schwach?

Vieles ist integraler Teil der Geschichte der deutschen Sprache. Musiktexte, Politikerreden, usw. Gut, antike, römische Texte wären noch deutlicher nicht unser Thema, aber dieses Argument widerlegt nur ein Ausschlusskriterium, es ist ein notwendiges, kein hinreichendes.

Handschriften zu entziffern, insbesondere Sütterlin, ist keine leichte Sache, wohl wahr, aber wieder allenfalls ein notwendiges, kein hinreichendes Argument.

Dass wir die nötige Userbasis haben, um die Aufgaben zu lösen, ist gar kein Argument. Fragen, die wir nicht lösen können, die aber on topic sind, bleiben ungelöst stehen. Wenn sie von allgemeinem Interesse sind, kommt vielleicht später jmd., und freut sich, sie lösen zu dürfen.

Das es keinen anderen Platz für die Fragen gibt, ist weder wahrscheinlich, noch belegt, zuletzt ein Argument. Mit dem gleichen Argument könnten wir Bewerbungsschreiben Korrekturlesen und Hausaufgaben lösen.

Dass solche Fragen für manche ein willkommenes Quiz darstellen glaube ich sofort. Für das Lösen von Hausaufgaben und Korrekturlesen von Briefen gilt das gleichermaßen. Es ist dennoch verpönt, weil es den Fokus des Auftritts in diese Richtung verschiebt, mehr Menschen mit ähnlichen Problemen werden kommen und Gleichbehandlung erwarten. Ob es die Ausnahme bleibt haben wir nicht selbst in der Hand.

Für die erwartete Qualität der Ergebnisse gilt wieder das gleiche, wie für die Fragen zuvor: Wir würden auch bei Übersetzungsanfragen und Korrekturlesen oft bessere Resultate hervorbringen, als der Fragesteller.

Dass Entzifferungsanfragen ein Pfad sind, auf dem Menschen nach einem besseren Verständnis der deutschen Sprache suchen, ist eine naive Utopie, die keines weiteren Kommentars würdig ist.

### Zusammenfassung:

Handschriften, Sütterlin oder verrottete Grabsteine zu entziffern ist ein schwieriger Prozess, bei dem gute Sprachkenntnisse von Vorteil sind, weil man dann Teile des Rätsels leichter erraten kann. Die überwältigende Mehrheit der Anfragen wird jedoch keine Hilfe für andere, mit ähnlichen Fragen sein. Eine Tabelle mit Sütterlinglyphen ist für den zweiten Fall sicher eine größere Hilfe.

Bei allem Verständnis für Hilfsbereitschaft: Stackexchange will keine Plattform für Gratisdienstleistungen sein. Wer auf die Zahl möglicher Fragen und Antworten schielt, der versucht die Plattform zu täuschen. Jeder ist frei einen Blog zu eröffnen und dort Gleichgesinnte zu versammeln, um genau diesen Service anzubieten, wenn er mag.

Ähnlich wie bei Hausaufgaben oder der Suche nach Formulierungshilfe für Anschreiben aller Art sollte die Regel lauten: Was einfach nur eine Dienstleistung ohne Bezahlung ist, keine verallgemeinerbare Antwort auf eine Frage, die in ihrer konkreten Gestalt nur ein Beispiel ist, sollte zurückgewiesen werden. Wenn eine allgemeine Frage aber an einem Beispiel illustriert wird, wenn andere Fragesteller hilfreiche Informationen mitnehmen können, ist es ok.

Comment: Leider muss ich hier zustimmen - Ich freue mich über Entzifferungsfragen, lese sie gerne, finde sie interessant und fände es schön, wenn german.SE ein Platz für sie wäre - aber die Argumente in dieser Antwort stimmen leider einfach.

Comment: I disagree to this (minority) opinion. I do not find an actual argument. I have been all over SE long enough, to know where the wind is blowing here, and no, I do not have amassed  fifty million reputation points, because I have an actual life outside of SE. IMO, all SEs have their share of those busy bodies who just want to close questions. They aren't actually providing any service with that, because if you don't like a question, just don't engage with it! It's so easy. You spend so much time arguing and obsession, and that kind-a explains why it's high rep people doing it.

Comment: My intention is not to offend anybody, nor belittle their reputation points, for sure they have answered many a difficult question with mastery of the subject. But why this obsession about making up reasons to close questions? All that matters is what this hand wringing writing here is admitting: it's interesting, it's useful, and people like to respond. As long as people like to respond, let them! How about trying a little freedom every once in a while?

Comment: If and when the number of deciphering or translation requests becomes overwhelming that they drown out "more deserving" questions, that is a time when one might look at this issue with such empiric data in hand, and that is a time when the decision becomes much clearer.