# Sind Fragen über die Entschlüsselung von Schriften (auch Handschriften) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Immer wieder tauchen Fragen zur Entschlüsselung von alten Schriften, meist Handschriften, auf. Sind diese erwünscht oder nicht? Auf den ersten Blick meint man sicherlich schnell nein, allerdings sind diese Fragen eine gern gesehene Abwechslung in der sonst recht oft schnöden Paragraphenreiterei. Für den OP ist es von großem Vorteil diese Frage hier zu stellen, erreicht man wohl sonst kaum mehr deutschsprachige "ExpertInnen" als auf dieser Plattform.

Jüngstes Beispiel: [Handwriting recognition in Gauss' Manuscript](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/37848/handwriting-recognition-in-gauss-manuscript)

Comment: Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic

Comment: What does the acronym "OP" stand for, and why is it used here?

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф Common abbreviation: "**O**riginal **P**oster" - the person who asked the question.

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф Or "**O**riginal **P**ost" - so the question itself.

Comment: Ich denke mal das Echo ist äußerst positiv und die Frage lässt sich eindeutig bejahen, zumal das Thema schon vor Jahren behandelt wurde, danke nochmal an @Takkat und sorry für die Dublette, allerdings ändert sich ja auch manches hier und das ist gut so. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are questions on reading of old handwritings on topic?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ich sehe keinen Grund, diese Sorte Fragen hier nicht zu stellen - Immerhin handelt es sich hier um deutsche Sprache, und "Schrift" gehört da eben auch dazu - vor allem, weil das Deutsche mit Sütterlin und anderen speziell deutschen Handschriften einige  Extraschwierigkeiten mitbringt, die man anderswo nur schwer beantwortet bekommt. Außerdem macht das Tüfteln an alten Handschriften auch Spaß ;)

Comment: Zustimmung. Bei deutschen Spezialschriften wie Sütterlin sollte sich die Frage überhaupt nicht stellen (im Wesentlichen ja eine Übersetzung Deutsch-zu-Deutsch, wo sollte das sonst gehen außer beim Profi..), bei normalen Handschriften aber vielleicht Einzelfallentscheidung wie bei normalen General-Reference-Fragen.

Comment: Endlich wird auch mal der Spaß-Faktor als Argument ins Treffen geführt. Danke! (Wenn auch die anderen Argumente vermutlich gewichtiger sind.)